# Getting the data of the object in Angular Object

Tags: angular

I have an object as you have seen below, I want to get the data called measurementPointName from the measurement tables contained in this object, how can I print it to the screen using angular.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XXxx.png)

I tried `*ngFor="let x of measurementTableList"` but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: it would help if you shared some more of your controller code. But basically you need to set the output of your console log onto a variable in the controller. Furthermore you have an array in an array so you will need 2 ngFor directives

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two *ngFor, one to cicle the "general array" of 2 elements and then one to cicle on measurementTableCalculations.

Into the second ngFor, you have to select the name field, so:

1: *ngFor="let SINGLE_ARRAY_ELEMENT of GENERAL_ARRAY_VARIABLE_NAME"

Assuming GENERAL_ARRAY_VARIABLE_NAME = worksList, you'll have:
*ngFor="let work of worksList" and this is your first div

into that, you have to go for
2: *ngFor="let measurementTableCalculation of work.measurementTableCalculations" and print the field measurementTableCalculation.name where you want it, so:

{{ measurementTableCalculation.name }}

Answer (score 0):

Your data returned as an array. You can access the data in the second index.

```js
// your data
apiResult = [
  {
    workOderId: 1234
    ...
  },
  {
    measurementTableList: [
      ...
    ]
  }
];
```

you then can acces the needed data by either putting the second index in different variable or just do:

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of apiResult[1].measurementTableList" ></div>
```